# Got stuck while trying to procced with sqoop import

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, sqoop

I am trying to import the data from MySQL to hadoop using below command

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.107/manusql --table sales --username TEST2 --P --target-dir /home/sqoopdata -m 3
```

But, the command execution got stuck at below process.

```
17/03/27 02:21:17 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/01b7ea34648fcad142b7f3e142a8f087/sales.jar
17/03/27 02:21:17 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
17/03/27 02:21:17 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
17/03/27 02:21:17 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
17/03/27 02:21:17 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
17/03/27 02:21:17 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of sales
```

Can someone help, please ?

Comment: add `-verbose` in your sqoop command to see extended logs

Answer (score 0):

Check resource manager logs there may be datatype incompatibility issue.Also try with -m 1 (single mapper) first for sequential access, then try for -m 3.